# How do you play a scale "in sixths" or "in thirds"?

Tags: guitar, theory, piano, scales

I have developed a new interest in music after many years, so I am brushing up on old stuff that I have long forgotten.

I'm watching some instructional videos which discuss  "playing a scale in **sixths**" or "playing a scale in **thirds**". The videos also refer to "fourths" and "fifths" in other lessons.

**What do these terms refer to?** Does it mean the length of the note (in beats)?

Answer (score 9):

Thirds and sixths are what are called **intervals**. They measure the distance between two pitches. When you count an interval, we count both the first pitch *and* the last pitch, so C up to E is a third (C is 1, D is 2, E is 3).

When the two pitches of an interval are played at the same time, we call it a *harmonic* interval. When the two pitches are played separately, it is a *melodic* interval.

So a C-major scale played in harmonic thirds would be C-E played together followed by D-F, E-G, F-A, etc.

We can also play a scale using *melodic* thirds, which would just be C E D F E G F A G B A C B D C.

(I would guess he means the latter definition, but the video was too long for me to find out.)

Comment: Yes he definitely means melodic 3rds and 6ths. It's a common practice technique for improvisation. At worst you learn the scale better but due to the melodic sound of 3rd and 6ths such patterns can find their way into solos as well. Also just in case it wasn't clear from the C major example, you play those intervals diatonically or within whatever scale you are targeting. So you don't always play a major 3rd, you might play a minor 3rd depending on the scale at hand.

Comment: Funny. On violin, the assumption (at least in my experience) is harmonic intervals when in the context of a scale.

Comment: @GeneralNuisance yeah, I hadn't even heard of playing scales in melodic intervals when I took my grade 8 violin, and there were definitely harmonic ones because I remember hating them!

Comment: Playing the melodic scale is excellent practice for all instruments, in part because those patterns show up all over the place in music.  For strings, playing harmonic double-stops is equally great practice for similar reasons.   Harmonic thirds, sixths, fourths, and octaves are good patterns to learn.